# Xcode debug broken MobileFirst 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are building a native iOS app that uses MFP 7.1 but are unable to watch variables or run 'po'.

Running e.g.'po myvar' on command line generates the output below. It looks related to the MFP include.

> IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.h:44:9: error: include of non-modular
>   header inside framework module 'IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation'
>   `#import <IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation/WLAnalytics.h>`
>
> too many errors emitted, stopping nowcould not build Objective-C
>   module 'IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation' Debug info from this module
>   will be unavailable in the debugger.
>
> error: Error in auto-import: failed to get module 'MyApp' from AST
>   context

Comment: On further investigation I believe this problem is related to using pods to configure the project. Importing frameworks manually resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the SDK via CocoaPods there is a defect in CocoaPods that may prevent compilation.

in Build Settings, go to "search header path" and remove the 3 existing entries in it. Then clean the project and try to build it again.